# Go back from remote "menu" button on tvOS (Apple TV) with React Native

Tags: objective-c, swift, react-native, tvos, apple-tv

I need to implement back from remote "menu" button on tvOS (Apple TV) and the BackHandler from 
React Native doesn't work. 
I understand that I have to use TVMenuControl and disable the TV menu key and go back, but this doesn't work even if the docs says it should work.

```
const backAction = () => {
Alert.alert("Hold on!", "Are you sure you want to go back?", [
  {
    text: "Cancel",
    onPress: () => null,
    style: "cancel"
  },
  { text: "YES", onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp() }
]);
return true;
```

};

```
useEffect(() => {
  BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", backAction);
return () =>
  BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", backAction);
}, []);
```

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance,
Claudiu

Comment: did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 3):

you need to enable the menu button functionality to make your code works

```
import {  TVMenuControl, BackHandler } from 'react-native';
....
useEffect(() => {
      TVMenuControl.enableTVMenuKey();
      BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", backAction);
    return () => {
     TVMenuControl.disableTVMenuKey();
      BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", backAction);
    }
    }, []);
```